# How to correct bind properties with ko.computed (Knockout.js)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I use Knockout.js and I face with this problem. The problem is property "newString" view incorrect data on page: "no image". I want to see another string: "image1". Help me to fix this problem.

```js
var viewModel = {
  new_property_first: ko.observable('image1'),
  new_property_second: ko.observable('image2'),

  newString: ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.new_property_first == 'image1') {
      return 'image1';
    } else if (this.new_property_second == 'image2') {
      return 'image2';
    } else {
      return 'no_image';
    }
  }, this),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p data-bind="text: newString"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem here is that you can't use `this` on object literals, you have to use [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). Also, you can't access [`observable`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) values directly, you have to *"call"* them like this :

```js
function ViewModel() {
  this.new_property_first = ko.observable('image1');
  this.new_property_second = ko.observable('image2');
  
  this.newString = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.new_property_first() == 'image1') {
      return 'image1';
    } else if (this.new_property_second() == 'image2') {
      return 'image2';
    } else {
      return 'no_image';
    }
  }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p data-bind="text: newString"></p>
```

Otherwise, if you want to stay with object literal, you can declare your `computed` outside the object declaration :

```js
var viewModel = {
  new_property_first: ko.observable('image1'),
  new_property_second: ko.observable('image2')
}

viewModel.newString = ko.computed(function() {
  if (this.new_property_first() == 'image1') {
    return 'image1';
  } else if (this.new_property_second() == 'image2') {
    return 'image2';
  } else {
    return 'no_image';
  }
}, viewModel)

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p data-bind="text: newString"></p>
```